# How to upgrade cURL to 7.71.0 in a docker image with centos7.x as the base

Tags: docker, curl, centos7

Title is pretty self explanatory, when using `yum upgrade curl` it doesn't upgrade curl beyond 7.29.0 witch is an issue because I need to use the `--retry-all-errors` flag in the docker images startup script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the below commands solved my issue

```
sudo rpm -Uvh http://www.city-fan.org/ftp/contrib/yum-repo/rhel7/x86_64/city-fan.org-release-2-2.rhel7.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install -y yum-utils
sudo yum-config-manager --disable city-fan.org
sudo yum -y --enablerepo=city-fan.org install libcurl libcurl-devel
```

If using the city-fan repo is an issue for you, you can also use this script to install directly from curl.

```
sudo yum install wget gcc openssl-devel make -y
wget https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-${VERSION}.tar.gz
tar -xzvf curl-${VERSION}.tar.gz 
rm -f curl-${VERSION}.tar.gz
cd curl-${VERSION}
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-ssl
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```